# C++ specialization of operator[] in unordered_map

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, template-specialization, unordered-map

I have been using `unordered_map<int, myObject>` with `myObject*` pointers to the objects in the unordered map. This has worked for a while, but I recently dicovered that I wrongly assumed that the memory location of myObject added to the unordered map would always remain the same.

I can solve the problem by using `unordered_map<int, myObject*>` and `new` and `delete` when adding and removing elements from the unordered map.

Since I have quite some code I would not want to add `new` and `delete` every place in the code where I am modifying the unordered map, I would rather try to overload the `unordered_map::operator[]` and `unordered_map::erase()` such that the usage of `new` and `delete` would happen transparently and I would not have to change my existing code. `unordered_map::operator[]` could then return a reference to the myObject itself rather than the pointer.

I have tried to inherit `unordered_map` but I am not sure how I should add the template argument list:

```
using namespace std;

template<class _Kty,
class _Ty,
class _Hasher = hash<_Kty>,
class _Keyeq = equal_to<_Kty>,
class _Alloc = allocator<pair<const _Kty, _Ty> > >
class  my_unordered_map : public unordered_map<_Umap_traits<_Kty, _Ty,
_Uhash_compare<_Kty, _Hasher, _Keyeq>, _Alloc, false> >
{

};
```

But I am getting errors such as:

```
error C2976: 'std::unordered_map' : too few template arguments
error C2955: 'std::unordered_map' : use of class template requires template argument list
```

Then I realized it might be possible to add a specialization to std when using the `myObject*` type with `unordered_map`, but I am not sure if it is even possible to overload the `operator[]` with a specialization.

I apprechiate any help I could get, thank you!

Edit:

I have now created a `template <class mapped_type>` class with an `unordered_map<int, mapped_type*>` as an internal structure. The `operator[]` was fairly straightforward to include:

```
template <class mapped_type> class MyMap {
public:
    std::unordered_map<int, mapped_type*> internal_map;

    mapped_type& operator[](int&& _Keyval)
    {   // find element matching _Keyval or insert with default mapped
        mapped_type*& ptr = internal_map[_Keyval];
        if (ptr == nullptr) ptr = new mapped_type();
        return *ptr;
    }
}

void erase(const int& _Keyval)
{   // erase and count all that match _Keyval
    mapped_type* ptr = internal_map[_Keyval];
    if (ptr) delete ptr;
    internal_map.erase(_Keyval);
}

void clear()
{   // erase all
    internal_map.clear();
}
```

Now the problem is the erase methods (default methods are included in `std::_Hash`). I do not really need an iterator so I guess the best way might be to use the `operator[]` method first to find the entry and then use `delete` before removing it from the `internal_map`, or do you have any other ideas that might be more suitable?

Edit: Added suggestion for erase. This makes sense right?

Comment: What about using a value-semantics wrapper of `myObject`? Something similar to `unique_ptr<myObject>` but with automatic creation of a `myObject` in the default ctor. Or you could use a `std::map`, its `insert` function does not invalidate references.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was not aware that the `std::map` did not invalidate the references. I have updated my question now and I will first try to solve it in the suggested manner.

Comment: You're changing a *copy* of the pointer stored in the map. You'd have to use something like `mapped_type*& ptr = internal_map[_Keyval];`

Comment: I am now using MyMap with two different classes, A and B. However, only when I use _MyMapA[integer]_ I get this error:
`error C2679: binary '[' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` and not on _MyMapB[integer]_. I don't see why this would make a difference whatsoever to the `Operator[]` method?

Comment: And what is strange is that when I substitute the int variable, i.e.: _MyMapA[integer]_ with a number _MyMapA[123]_ I do not get any errors.

Comment: Oh, I've missed that. `mapped_type& operator[](int&& _Keyval)` is taking an *rvalue* reference, so you can't bind it to an lvalue `int`. In this case, if you *really* don't want to use a (unordered) map of a wrapper, then you could use use `mapped_type& operator[](int _Keyval)`

Comment: "I recently dicovered that I wrongly assumed that the memory location of myObject added to the unordered map would always remain the same." You were correct, and are now mistaken: operations that modify an `unordered_map` can invalidate *iterators*, but not pointers or references to elements (with the obvious exception of erased elements). The elements themselves will never move.

Comment: @dyp Thank you very much again! I could probably use a wrapper, but I'm not so experienced in c++ and since I've used the whole day to get this to work I think I'll use it like this for now.

Comment: @Casey Thank you very much for your input! I did a check where they were the pointers were suddenly pointing to other items in the list. However, I recreated a similar test now and it seems to be working fine. It might have something to do with using two threads, I will investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

To inherit from `std::unordered_map` it is sufficient to use

```
template <class T,class V> 
class MyMap : public unordered_map<T, V>
```

if its ok for you to use the std allocator and hash function. But beware, that there isn't a virtual destructor in the standard containers.

Anyway, what you want to do in the end sounds to me like you want to have an [intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/intrusive/intrusive_vs_nontrusive.html) container. If so, then there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213334/boost-intrusive-and-unordered-map) related SO question.

Comment: Inheriting from standard containers is not such a great idea

Comment: @n.m. added a disclaimer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have now updated my question, it seems like I will be able to solve the problem this way.